# How to refresh data in a bwu_datagrid

Tags: dart, bwu-datagrid

I'm attempting to refresh an existing datagrid in the following manner, but that results in rendering errors, like rows still appearing.  What is the appropriate way to do this?

```dart
void onData( Map<String,Data> data_ ){
  if( identical(data,data_) ) return;
  data = data_;
  if( provider == null ){
    provider = new MapDataItemProvider();
    grid.setup(dataProvider: dataProvider, columns:columns, gridOptions: gridOptions);
  }else{
    dataProvider.items.clear();
  }
  data.forEach( (k,v) => provider.add( toMapped(k,v) );
  grid.render();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`invalidateAllRows()` is another way to notify the grid that the data has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the DataView example, it appears there are a few calls other than render() to be made.

- grid.invalidateRows(e.changedRows);
- grid.updateRowCount();
- grid.invalidateAllRows()

but the best way is probably `invalidate()`
Duh.

After adding `invalidate()`, the grid was redrawing correctly...

```dart
void onData( Map<String,Data> data_ ){
  if( identical(data,data_) ) return;
  data = data_;
  if( provider == null ){
    provider = new MapDataItemProvider();
    grid.setup(dataProvider: dataProvider, columns:columns, gridOptions: gridOptions);
  }else{
    dataProvider.items.clear();
  }
  data.forEach( (k,v) => provider.add( toMapped(k,v) );
  grid.invalidate();
}
```

Code for Invalidate from [github bwu_datagrid](https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid/blob/master/lib/bwu_datagrid.dart)

```dart
void invalidate() {
  updateRowCount();
  invalidateAllRows();
  render();
 }
```