# bwu_datagrid setColumns dynamically deforms while running as JS

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, bwu-datagrid

I was able to dynamically update the columns/data by using something like this:

```html
void setDV(List<Column> cols, List<DataItem> datum) {
    print('setColnData cols.length: ${columns.length}, datum.length: ${data2.length}');
    this.data2.clear();
    print("--1: ${data2.length}");
    if(this.columns.length < 1){
      this.columns = cols;
      grid.setColumns = columns;
    }
    datum.forEach((e) => this.data2.add(e));
    print("--2: ${data2.length}");
    grid.invalidate();
  }
```

Which works in Chromium flawlessly as a Dart app. I'm able to pass new columns with different renderers, properties, etc. But, If I run my project as JS, it works just as expected on Chrome and it fails in both FireFox and Safari. All the columns appear scrounged up and the top headers are all gone. (I have a picture, but I lack the pointage to post it here).

Also, I'm including 'dart_support.js' on my entrypoint, because without it bwu_datagrid would not show up while running as JS.

I guess my questions are:
A) Am I updating the columns/data incorrectly?
B) Is this expected behavior for now...
C) I overlooked a small detail somewhere.

Thanks in advanced for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: I have to try it but as far as I remember calling `grid.render()` after setting the columns should fix it.

Comment: Per the comments of this response:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834635/how-to-refresh-data-in-a-bwu-datagrid),
invalidate() calls  render() at the very end.

Comment: Adding grid.render() after grid.invalidate() allows me to see the new data, grid.render() by itself didn't do anything. The second I show/hide a column by the BwuColumnPicker everything is messed up again. It looks like every time the columns change post render everything gets messed up in FF/safari.

BTW >> Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, and for this awesome port!, there aren't that many Dart datagrids out there.

Comment: I found a discussion about a similar problem https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid/issues/97 please let me know if this helps in your case.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work. I tried setting the listener that resets the columns when attached, but no luck. I also tried setting the columns = (columns), no luck. What I'm seeing in FF/Safari is very close to this:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid_playground/master/web/issue97_re_attach/ressources/datagrid_broken_layout.png  But without any column headers. I'm wondering, looking at my function above, am I setting the columns @ the wrong time/place? I'm also using a dataView, 'data2' is its data.

Comment: Is it urgent? I have a few problems myself currently where I only make slow progress :-(

Comment: Gunter, no urgency. I know man, you're probably swamped. I sold this awesome grid to my manager, and I managed to dazzle them with a POC. But, you know how it is, we need to customize this for dynamic population. I'll love to use bwu grid, I just thought I give this site a try. It seems like changing columns on the fly messes things up while in JS mode. Again, thank you for your awesome contribution, if there is a newer version in the works, I can wait and see.

Comment: Great! It is a known problem and I have some ideas how to solve it but I need a longer time block to dive into the code ;-)